# gcc including GMP library and osx mavericks

Tags: c, gmp, osx-mavericks

I am not able to compile C programs that use the gmp library under OSX mavericks, it says that it cannot find the **gmp.h** header file, I comiled the program like this `gcc factor.c -lgmp`, but it would not recognize the linker flag.

How can i compile C programs that use GMP?